# Install Windows Phone 8 application on multiple windows phones for testing

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have developer account and have a Windows Phone 8 application ready for testing. The app has still not made to the Windows Store but I would like my friends without developer accounts to test it out on their phones. I have it deployed on my windows phone 8 using VS, Is there a way to do it on their phones? Ideally, i would like to email them a package for deployment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Beta testing distribution model for Windows Phone 8 Apps. Essentially it enables you to make an app available via the store to a limited set of users, without having to pass the bar on all the app store requirements. When you upload the app you specify the Windows Account IDs (aka Live IDs) of the intended recipients (aka your friends).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx

Be careful as there is a gotcha. The name (or identifier) of the app must be unique within the store, so don't call your Beta version app the name that you want for your Release version app.

Comment: Thanks @Shed Magnet that's very useful, wasn't aware of it. It seems like the best option and I will definitely give it a try!